Moving an object from a random point A to a set point B
I'm learning through Unity Learn to make games in Unity, and I'm finally starting to catch on to using C#. Unfortunately, I ran into a problem with my code. I'm making a game with customers walking up to a register, and I need them to spawn from a random set of coordinates and walk to a set point.
I've tried using code I made in the past, while also looking at a few different tutorials and tips, all of it ending with the same result. I need them to spawn between ((-7, 5), 7.8, -19) and move to (-1, 7.8, -7.5). No matter what I try, the customers spawn in the air and float to above the point they need to go to. It seems to be doubling the coordinate numbers, yet they do exactly the same thing if I cut the numbers in half. I thought it might help if I added a rigidbody, yet that only caused the customer to fall endlessly when reaching what they thought was point B. Any suggestions?
This is the code I'm working with currently.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CustomerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 beginPos = new Vector3(-1f, 7.8f, -19f);
    private Vector3 endPos = new Vector3(-1f, 7.8f, -7.5f);
    public float time = 5;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Move(beginPos, endPos, time));
    }

    IEnumerator Move(Vector3 beginPos, Vector3 endPos, float time)
    {
        for(float t = 0; t < 1; t += Time.deltaTime / time)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(beginPos, endPos, t);
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}


Well so currently you start at a fixed point and move to a another fixed point ... if you want the first one to be random .. then generate a random one as beginPos ...

I can't test out this code, so please let me know if you experience more problems.
I simply set the initial position to a random coordinate within your target range before calling the movement function.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CustomerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 beginPos = new Vector3(-1f, 7.8f, -19f);
    private Vector3 endPos = new Vector3(-1f, 7.8f, -7.5f);
    public float time = 5;

    void Start()
    {
        Vector3 randomSpawnPos = new Vector3(Random.Range(-7f, 7f), 7.8f, Random.Range(-19f, 7.8f));

        // Initial pos of customers
        transform.position = randomSpawnPos;
        
        StartCoroutine(Move(randomSpawnPos, endPos, time));
    }


    IEnumerator Move(Vector3 beginPos, Vector3 endPos, float time)
    {
        float startY = transform.position.y;

        for(float t = 0; t < 1; t += Time.deltaTime / time)
        {
            Vector3 intermediatePos = Vector3.Lerp(beginPos, endPos, t);

            transform.position = intermediatePos;
            yield return null;
        }
        // 
        transform.position = endPos;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}


The intermediatePos.y is quite redundant

Thank you for the answer! It didn't quite fix the issue, but I realized what I was doing wrong. I think it was both a mixture of having the wrong bits selected in my Rigidbody and also not having the correct values for where they were spawning. I feel a bit dumb, but I do really appreciate the help!

your current code looks good, to make a random spawn all you should need is a function to generate random x and z values and create an object at that position after which your current movement script should work well. Seems like you have tried something to create a random spawn already it would help if you could show the code here.
